# Mocking ConfigurationManager.AppSettings with JustMock

Tags: c#, justmock

Following the directions at: http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/advanced-usage-static-mocking.html

I'm unsuccessful in mocking ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.  Here's the code I'm using...

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void my_test()
{
    // Arrange
    var appSettings = new NameValueCollection {
        { "test1", "one" }
    };

    Mock.Arrange(() => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
        .Returns(appSettings)
        .MustBeCalled();

    // Act
    var test1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test1"];

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("one", test1);
}
```

This is the error I receive.

Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:. Actual:<(null)>.

Is it possible to mock this object?

[edit] I'm also using the Trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/justmock/general-discussions/problems-mocking-the-configurationmanager-appsettings.aspx

Official response is, this appears to be an issue with MSTest only.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried your test and it worked as expected:

```
// Arrange 
var appSettings = new NameValueCollection { { "test1", "one" } };

Mock.Arrange(() => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
    .Returns(appSettings)
    .MustBeCalled();

// Act 
var test1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test1"];

// Assert 
Assert.AreEqual("one", test1);
```

Here please make sure that **Configuration.AppSettings** is not already invoked in some static constructor of your project.

Here to note that *.net* profiler intercepts during *OnJITCompilationStarted* and this fires only once for a given member.

Moreover, please make sure that your profiler is configured properly and JM plugin for VS is installed. You can check if the profiler is enabled by  **Mock.IsProfilerEnabled**.

Finally, you generally dont need to use **Mock.SetupStatic(#TARGET_TYPE#)**, unless you are doing strict mock or want to fake static constructor for a given type. When you will be doing *Mock.Arrange*, it will automatically set the interceptors if not already.

[Note: I used the latest version]

Comment: Strange, I still can't get it to work.  Maybe there is a limitation in the trial?  I created a fresh JustMock Test project directly from the template and I still can't get it to pass.  I even added this (which passes) Assert.IsTrue(Mock.IsProfilerEnabled);